# How to check if string contains numbers within square brackets

Tags: python, regex

I'm analysing files by name.

- I want to exclude files that contain numbers within square brackets.
- I want to keep files that contain words within square brackets.

Example filename to exclude:

```
Kickloop [124].wav
```

Example filename to include:

```
Boomy [Kick].wav
```

My code currently ignores **all** file names including square brackets.

```
def contains_square_brackets(file):
    if ("[" in file) and ("]" in file):
        return True
```

**Question:** Is there a regex way of achieving what I am after?

Comment: What about words without brackets at all? Keep or not keep?

Comment: [Something like this](https://regex101.com/r/poesBK/2)?

Comment: should `foo.wav` be kept or not? Should `foo[].wav` be kept or not? should `foo[123bar].wav` be kept or not? Should `foo[123][bar][].wav` be kept or not?

Answer (score 6):

The regex `r'\[\d+\]'` will help you. When used correctly it will identify strings containing square brackets surrounding *one or more* digits.

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> def has_numbers_in_square_brackets(s):
...     return bool(re.search(r'\[\d+\]', s))
... 
>>> has_numbers_in_square_brackets('Hello')
False
>>> has_numbers_in_square_brackets('Hello[123]')
True
>>> has_numbers_in_square_brackets('Hello[dog]')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pythons stdlib `re` module for regex matching.

Whats regex?

A regular expression is a special sequence of characters that helps you match or find other strings or sets of strings, using a specialized syntax held in a pattern.

How do i use the `re` module for regex matching?

Well you can use this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm) to help further your understandng.

The pattern you're looking for is `\[\d+\]` and that means to look for a constant stream of digits inside a opening and closing square brackets.

But this would be my solution to your issue using the module:

```
import re

if re.match('\[\d+\]', file_name):
    print('File contains numbers in square brackets')
else:
    print('File does not contain numbers in square brackets
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
import re

re_pattern = '\[(\d*)\]'
prog = re.compile(re_pattern)

teststrings = ['Kickloop [124].wav', 'Kickloop [aaa].wav']

for teststring in teststrings:
    result = prog.search(teststring)

    if result is None:
        print(teststring + ' no match')
    else:
        print(teststring + ' matched')
```

**Output:**

```
Kickloop [124].wav matched
Kickloop [aaa].wav no match
```

More reading here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html